# Are there any guarantees about the relative addresses of __DATA labels?

Tags: c, unix, x86-64

When compiled with Clang/LLVM (Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.49) 
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0) the C code below prints out 22. I am not actually concerned about the C standard but I want to know if there is a way to make a label such that at -8 byte offset from it there is another quad word of my choosing. I would like it to work on Mac OS X and Linux.

```
#include<stdio.h>

long long x = 22;
long long y = 33;

int main(void) {
  long long diff = *(&y - 1);
  printf("%lld\n",diff);
}
```

with the relavant part of the DATA section.

```
   .section  __DATA,__data
   .globl  _x                      ## @x
   .align  3
 _x:
   .quad 22                      ## 0x16

   .globl  _y                      ## @y
   .align  3
 _y:
   .quad 33                      ## 0x21
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is free to put static/global objects in any order it wants.  Same for functions.  A compiler might try to group "hot" or "cold" data or functions together, to reduce the cache footprint.

If you want to reference multiple things from one base pointer, put them in a struct or array.  As @kcraigie suggests in a comment, a `union` between an array and a struct is possible.  (But probably isn't useful).

Array layout in memory is guaranteed.  `struct` layout has some guarantees, too, but may not forbid compiler from putting padding where you don't expect it.  `struct` layout is fixed for a given ABI, though, so you can depend on the same struct layout from all compilers that target the same ABI on the same platform.

If you really care about layout in memory, you could give symbolic names to different array elements with an `enum`, or with macros to define `GLOBAL_X` to `global_array[0]` or something.  Otherwise just use a `struct`, which will work well if your purpose in grouping things together is to be able to copy them as a block.

---

Contrary to @kcraigie's answer, there's no need to dynamically allocate the block of memory.  A static array or struct will do the job just fine.  Obviously, static storage is a waste if you don't need it: use automatic (stack) storage when possible.

---

re: question in comments:

> Would an assembler keep them right next to each if placed in the data section like that?

Yes.  Assemblers just assemble bytes into an object file, with no scope for moving things around *within a section*.  `.align` directives can produce gaps, but we know the `.align` between x and y will expand to 0 bytes (because of the `.align` before x, putting it at an 8-byte boundary already).

The different sections (`.text` / `.rodata` vs. `.data` vs. any custom sections) are only put into their final order at link time, though.

Answer (score 0):

Any sane C compiler should put them in contiguous memory but it's not guaranteed. The only way AFAIK is to allocate a block of memory yourself either on the stack or heap (or globally), then you will be guaranteed contiguous memory.

Comment: don't globals go in the data section not the stack or the heap?

Comment: Would an assembler keep them right next to each if placed in the data section like that?

Comment: Again, a sane compiler should do so but I don't believe it's guaranteed. You can try a union of a block of memory and 2 longs, but I'm not sure that's guaranteed either. Best thing to do is manage the memory yourself.

Comment: You don't need to avoid static allocation.  A static array or struct has the same layout guarantees as a dynamic array or struct.  That's how you work with a "block" of memory in C.